# Как скроллбаром в Panel скролить background этой Panel'и?

Tags: c#, winforms

Делаю программу на WindowsForms. Некое подобие чертежной программы, с миллиметровкой на заднем фоне. И можно сказать, что панель в моей программе это некая рабочая область, я могу drag&drop' ом перетаскивать на эту панель некоторые другие контролы и работать с ними, при уходе контрола за границу, появляется скролл бар и по сути данная панель может быть бесконечной. Но, background слишком большим быть не может из-за памяти, поэтому сделал вот как:   изначально background' ом становится bitmap, равный размеру панели (просто в нем е.Graphics'om рисую линии одну за другой и появляется подобие миллиметровки). И когда какой-нибудь контрол уходит за пределы  видимости панели, появляется скролл бар  для прокручивания. Все  работает нормально, контролы  скролятся, но вот background стоит статично и не двигается  при скролле, хотя нужно  чтобы двигался  вместе с элементами.
Изначально подумывал просто двигать background на то значение на которое наскролил, а потом вырезать ту область, что вышла  за пределы панели, а потом приклеивать её в конец, но не знаю как это реализовать со встроенными скролл барами, плюс жрет очень много памяти, до 2гб может вырасти, хотя программа того не стоит.
Как это можно реализовать?

Вот что я пытался сделать с кастомными скролл барами (логика сдвига и приклеивания битмапа):

```
public Bitmap DrawImageUnscaled(int x, int y, int width, int height)
{
        Bitmap croppedPartBitmpap = new Bitmap(width, height);
        Rectangle croppedPartRectangle = new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);

        //BigBitmap - изначальный битмап 
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(this.BigBitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(this.BigBitmap, 0, 0, croppedPartRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        } 

        Bitmap leftPartBitmap = new Bitmap(this.PanelWidth - width, height);
        Rectangle leftPartRectangle = new Rectangle(width, y, this.PanelWidth - width, height);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(leftPartBitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(this.BigBitmap, 0, 0, leftPartRectangle, GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
        }


        Bitmap mergedBitmap = new Bitmap(this.PanelWidth, this.PanelHeight);
        using (var g = Graphics.FromImage(mergedBitmap))
        {
            g.DrawImage(leftPartBitmap, 0, 0);
            g.DrawImage(croppedPartBitmpap, leftPartBitmap.Width, 0);
        }
        return mergedBitmap;
}
```

Comment: `BackgroundImage` имеется ввиду?

Comment: @defaultlocale да, это имел ввиду, извиняюсь.

Comment: Там одно большое изображение, которое не вмещается на панель? Или оно дублируется ([`ImageLayout.Tile`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.imagelayout))? Если составите пример, будет проще понять проблему.

Comment: @defaultlocale Я поставил туда битмап, который сам рисую до этого, с размером, равным этой самой панели. Я немного отредактировал вопрос, не могли бы вы, пожалуйста, посмотреть, если будет время ? Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Простой вариант:

- Не задавать `BackgroundImage` для панели.
- Добавить на панель `PictureBox` с нужным изображением позади всех остальных элементов.
- Задать изображению нужный размер.
- Панели установить `AutoScroll = true`.

В этом варианте панель будет прокручивать «фоновый» PictureBox.

Если нужно прокручивать именно `BackgroundImage` панели, то есть вариант с перерисовкой панели и установкой [`AutoScrollMinSize`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.scrollablecontrol.autoscrollminsize?view=netframework-4.8). Почитайте ответ здесь: [Scrollable backgroundimage of a tablelayout in winforms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346852/scrollable-backgroundimage-of-a-tablelayout-in-winforms)